Dpdk packets corruptions using PcapPlusPlus
I'm using the dpdk api in PcapPlusPlus with a computer that has 32Gb Ram , 16 cores and 10 Gbp/s fiber optical sfp support.
However,with this configuration (im guessing, mainly the "MAX_RECEIVE_BURST" and "HEAP_PAKCET_CAPACITY")
I'm getting quite a lot of errouns packets, is there a known way to optimize it?
Or some benchmarks to test it?
Thanks in advance for the help.
here's the code:
#include <memory>
#include <optional>

#include "DpdkDeviceList.h"
#include "PayloadLayer.h"
#include "UdpLayer.h"

#include "PacketsHeap.hpp"

class DpdkReceiver 
{
    pcpp::DpdkDeviceList* _device;
    std::shared_ptr<PacketsHeap> _heap;
    
    static constexpr auto PACKET_SIZE = 9000;
    static constexpr auto DEVICE_PORT = 0;
    static constexpr auto QUEUE_ID = 0;
    static constexpr auto TX_QUEUE_COUNT = 0;
    static constexpr auto RX_QUEUE_COUNT = 1;
    static constexpr auto MEM_POOL = 65535;
    static constexpr auto MAX_RECEIVE_BURST = 1500;
    static constexpr auto HEAP_PACKET_CAPACITY = 100000;
    
public:
    static constexpr auto CORE_MASK = 3;
    
DpdkReceiver(std::uint16_t packet_size = PACKET_SIZE)
:
    _heap(std::make_shared<PacketsHeap>(HEAP_PACKET_CAPACITY, packet_size))
    {
    if(!pcpp::DpdkDeviceList::getInstance().getDeviceByPort(DEVICE_PORT)
    {
    //Throw exception
    }
    if(!_device->openMultiQueues(RX_QUEUE_COUNT, TX_QUEUE_COUNT))
    {
    //Throw exception
    }
    if(!_device->setMtu(packet_size))
    {
    //Throw exception
    }
}
    
    
std::optional<std::shared_ptr<std::vector<SmartPacket>> receivePackets()
{
    std::vector<pcpp::MBufRawPacket*> raw_packets(MAX_RECEIVE_BURST, nullptr);
    auto packets_received = _device->receivePackets(raw_packets.data() , MAX_RECEIVE_BURST, QUEUE_ID);
    
    if(packets_received == 0)
    {
        return {};
    }
    return { std::move(parseToSmartPackets(raw_packets.data() , packets_received))};
}
    
    
    
std::shared_ptr<<std::vector<SmartPacket>> parseToSmartPackets(pcpp::MBufRawPacket** rawPackets , std::uint64_t packetsReceived)
{
    auto smartPackets = std::make_shared<std::vector<SmartPacket>>();
    
    for(int i=0; i < packetsReceived; i++)
    {
        auto rawPacket = rawPackets[i]'
        defer freePacket([rawPacket]) { delete rawPacket; });
    
        auto optionalSmartPacket = parsePacket(rawPacket);
        if(optionalSmartPacket)'
        {
            smartPackets->emplace_back(std::move(optionalSmartPacket.value()));
        }
    }
    return smartPackets;
}
    
std::optional<SmartPacket> parsePacket(pcpp::MBufRawPacket* rawPacket)
{
    pcpp::Packet packet(rawPacket); 
    auto udpLayer = packet.getLayerOfType<pcpp::UdpLayer>();
    if(payloadLayer = dynamic_cast<pcpp::PayloadLayer*>(packet.getLastLayer())
    {
        return { SmartPacket(payloadLayer->getPayload() , payloadLayer->getPayloadLen(), _heap , be16toh(udpLayer->getUdpHeader()->portDst)) };
    }
    return {};
}
    
//I've got another class that runs while True:
    
auto packets = _dpdk_receiver->receivePackets(); 

I tried to use PcapPlusPlus dpdk api to receive packet in an optimal way, I ended with tons of corrupted data

what's defer? what's SmartPacket? please show a [mre]

As we discussed over email. maybe PACKET_SIZE of 9000 (jumbo packets) is why these packets get corrupted. With the latest PcapPlusPlus version in master you can modify the mMbufDataSize which might solve the issue
